# Is it possible to rename a Cloud SQL database using the gcloud CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud-cli

I would like to rename a Cloud SQL database using only the `gcloud` CLI.
I can see that I [can `patch` a database](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/databases) using the CLI. However it seems to only patch either the *collation* or the *charset* but not the database name itself.
Do you know if there is a way to achieve it with the CLI ?

If not, I will use a [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) and run the `ALTER` command directly on the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think, there is an in-built option to rename database using [gcloud command-line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/databases).

Available option is login to database engine and alter database name using [ALTER DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rename-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16) command, if it supports in-place database alteration.

Another option is use [gcloud sql to export](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/export/sql#--database) your database to sql file, make changes to your database name and [import](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/sql#--database) it back to Cloud SQL instance.

If you are using Cloud SQL MySQL instance, you can use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to backup and restore with new database name or use [rename table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-table.html) with new database name.